# How to Implement Audit.NET for DotNet Framework 4.6.1 ? Following Code will work not for .Net Framework but for not for DotNetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I applied this code block to the startup file in my .Net framework 4.6.1 web api mvc project.

It's connected to the Postgresql database

[image]

I added configuration to Startup class

It's say's no error, but does not update the audit table

[image]

I used following documntation
https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/tree/master/src/Audit.NET.PostgreSql

[image: x`]

this sample usage of dotnet core

```
{
  "EndDate": "2022-03-01T05:05:42.7452589Z",
  "Duration": 36,
  "EventType": "PgDbContext",
  "StartDate": "2022-03-01T05:05:42.7094888Z",
  "Environment": {
    "Culture": "en-US",
    "UserName": "Dasun",
    "DomainName": "DESKTOP-*****",
    "MachineName": "DESKTOP-*/****",
    "AssemblyName": "Audit.EntityFramework.Core, Version=19.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=***********",
    "CallingMethodName": "Audit.EntityFramework.DbContextHelper+<CreateAuditScopeAsync>d__31.MoveNext()"
  },
  "EntityFrameworkEvent": {
    "Result": 1,
    "Entries": [
      {
        "Name": "ServerType",
        "Table": "ServerTypes",
        "Valid": true,
        "Action": "Insert",
        "PrimaryKey": {
          "Id": "a123bee8-41a4-4945-acc3-91d0c741095d"
        },
        "ColumnValues": {
          "Id": "a123bee8-41a4-4945-acc3-91d0c741095d",
          "Name": "SAP HANA",
          "IsActive": true,
          "CreatedAt": "2022-03-01T05:05:42.7059568Z",
          "CreatedBy": "Daxx Mod",
          "DeletedAt": null,
          "DeletedBy": null,
          "IsDeleted": false,
          "UpdatedAt": null,
          "UpdatedBy": null
        }
      }
    ],
    "Success": true,
    "Database": "uyg",
    "ContextId": "b3dea36b-*************-*****:0"
  }
}
```

Comment: You show just a setup and not the usage. Do you tried showing two different images?

Comment: I added the picture..

Comment: I still don't see a usage.

Comment: I updated it usage is automatically saved all the database transactions in database

Comment: What do you mean by usage?

Comment: The documentation you linked has another link to the usage section. Have you done what is described there (https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#usage)?

Comment: Yes , I done with relevent  https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.NET.PostgreSql/README.md